# Does python code slow down when logging is set to high level?

Tags: python, performance, logging, python-logging

If I have multiple `logging.info(...)` inside my code, but the level is set to `logging.WARN`, the logs are not displayed in the console. But do those infos still have a significant impact on the code execution speed?

Comment: Yes, they have *an* impact. Whether it is significant depends on the amount and complexity of the log statements.

Answer (score 1):

They indeed have an impact. For a logger with a `StreamHandler` with both levels set to `logging.WARNING`, I compared 3 functions: `logging.info`, `logging.warning` and doing nothing (`pass`).

```py
import logging

from functools import wraps
from time import time

def timing(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrap(*args, **kw):
        ts = time()
        result = f(*args, **kw)
        te = time()
        print(f"func:{f.__name__} took: {te-ts} sec")
        return result
    return wrap

handler = logging.StreamHandler()
handler.setLevel(logging.WARNING)

logger = logging.getLogger("foobarlogger")
logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
logger.propagate = False
logger.addHandler(handler)

def do_nothing():
    pass

def log_info():
    logger.info("INFO foo bar")

def log_warn():
    logger.warning("WARN foo bar")

N = 1000000

@timing
def run_n_times_info():
    for _ in range(N):
        log_info()

@timing
def run_n_times_warn():
    for _ in range(N):
        log_warn()

@timing
def run_n_times_nothing():
    for _ in range(N):
        do_nothing()

run_n_times_warn()
run_n_times_info()
run_n_times_nothing()
```

It gives:

| N | run_n_times_warn (in ms) | run_n_times_info (in ms) | run_n_times_nothing (in ms) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100000 | 4795 | 49 | 11 |
| 1000000 | 46509 | 434 | 103 |
| 10000000 | 526205 | 6150 | 1416 |

You can see that even without printing anything to the console, the `run_n_times_info` is consistently running at least 4 times slower than the `do_nothing` function, but it's still much faster than actually printing to the console (by a factor of ~100 in my tests).